# How can i merge one object smoothly into another while animating?

Tags: animation, mesh, edit-mode, shape-keys

[image]

[image]

so i have a baby as one object and a toilet as one object and the baby grows. at the end it is supposed to have the toilet as a head like the first grown person on the right. 
how can i merge the toilet head with the fully grown baby at the end while animating so that i can keep on animating it as one object together and so that the colours are a nicer gradient?
does it work somehow with shape keys? but then i'd have to rebuild the whole toilet and i'd need it to look (at least almost) exactly like the first so copying the toilet would be kind of necessary.
if someone could help me that would be fantastic. :)

Comment: Shape keys would be one possibility, although I'm not sure this could be entirely done with 3D models alone. It may require some composition and some fading transitions made in post production

Comment: @Lisa LOL What a character concept. Is there any symbolism behind it? :)

Comment: @Paul Gonet I dub it the Trump effect.

Comment: @PaulGonet thank you! :D in the video you only see those two characters, the grown up toilethead person and the baby transforming into one and the camera pans to show another toilet next to the grown up baby so it's back to the starting frame and the video loops and that way you can imagine there being an entire endless row of toilets and people bearing a kid and making them grow up the same way they did. for me personally it is about unhealthy mechanisms you learn from parents and how they are passed on in the family. some i talked to also see a more general negative view on humanity. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use *shape keys* to make such animation, but it demands joining the objects together.
[image]

Join the meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Connect the meshes' vertices in *Edit Mode*. Try to keep the topology clean. After making it one solid mesh add two additional *edge loops* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and place them as pictured below. These will be helpful for further creasing.
[image]

Go to *Data header*-->*Shape Keys panel* and add two *shape keys* being in *Object Mode*. Select the second one, press *apply shapekeys in edit mode* button and change its value to *1.000*. Select the bottom of the character's neck in *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->Cursor to Selected (with a *3D cursor* as a *pivot point* set). Use a *border select* tool (<kbd>B</kbd>) to select all the body vertices. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num-</kbd> to unselect the very top *edge loop*. Press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> to scale vertices. Slide the *edge loops* pictured above (press <kbd>G</kbd> twice) to crease the edge of a toilet. Your transformation animation is ready.
[image]

Now being in *Object Mode* apply the transformations to the object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). Change the value of the *shape key* to *1.000* and keyframe it with <kbd>I</kbd>. Select the object and move it down (<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>). Place it on the grid floor, then press <kbd>I</kbd>-->*Location*. Now go further on a *timeline*, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to reset location, then keyframe the location again with <kbd>I</kbd>. Change the value of a *shape key* to *0.000* and keyframe it again.
[image]

Here's the .blend [image]

Comment: OH! i only just saw this!! i solved it really complicatedly with a scaled down body hidden inside the toilet in the final video but your approach makes so much more sense and looks MUCH smoother! im sorry i didnt see this sooner! maybe i'll redo it this way. anyways, thank you so much for this tutorial! it makes me really happy! :)